# The word “chimiste” in Baudelaire's “Au Lecteur”

Tags: sens, poésie

This question is about the following stanza of Baudelaire's opening poem *[Au Lecteur](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal/1861/Au_lecteur)* to *Les Fleurs du mal:*

> Sur l'oreiller du mal c'est Satan Trismégiste
>   Qui berce longuement notre esprit enchanté,
>   Et le riche métal de notre volonté
>   Est tout vaporisé par ce savant chimiste.

This “chimiste” is commonly translated to English as “alchemist”:

> On evil's pillow lies the alchemist
>   Satan Thrice-Great, who lulls our captive soul,
>   And all the richest metal of our will
>   Is vaporized by his hermetic arts.
>
> *– James McGowan*
>
> Cradled in evil, that Thrice-Great Magician,
>   The Devil, rocks our souls, that can't resist;
>   And the rich metal of our own volition
>   Is vaporised by that sage alchemist.
>
> *– Roy Campbell*
>
> On the pillow of evil Satan, Trismegist,
>   Incessantly lulls our enchanted minds,
>   And the noble metal of our will
>   Is wholly vaporized by this wise alchemist.
>
> *– William Aggeler*
>
> Pillowed on evil, Satan Trismegist
>   Ceaselessly cradles our enchanted mind,
>   The flawless metal of our will we find
>   Volatilized by this rare alchemist.
>
> *– Jacques LeClercq*

This seems fitting because Baudelaire invokes images / symbolism of alchemy. But if we consult a dictionary, “chimiste” does just mean “chemist” in English. Contrarily, the English “alchemist” would be “alchimiste” in French.

One rare translation of *Au Lecteur* which uses the dictionary translation, has a certain anachronistic vibe to it:

> On the pillow of evil it is Satan Trismegistus
>   Who soothes a long while our bewitched mind,
>   And the rich metal of our determination
>   Is made vapor by that learned chemist.
>
> *– Eli Siegel*

So the question is:

- Are the translations by McGowan, Aggeler, Campbell and LeClercq basically just distorting the meaning? We're talking about a mid-19th century work, after Lavoisier and de Fourcroy; while in the 18th century the differentiation between “chimie” and “alchimie” may not have been fully complete, at this time it surely was?
- If indeed a faithful translation of “chimiste” in this poem would just be “chemist”, i.e. “a rational man of  science”, without hinting at an occult discipline, what could be an explanation (aside from lyrical technicalities) for Baudelaire's choice of this word? Was the anachronism intended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Alexandrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_alexandrine) requirements might have played a (minor) role. ***Par ce savant chimiste*** is a fine hemistich but ***par ce savant alchimiste*** doesn't work. Maybe Baudelaire preferred the former to potential alternatives using *alchimiste*.

In any case, *savant chimiste* looks appropriate here. *Alchimiste* (a dreamer, a loser searching in vain something that doesn't exist) would have been ill-suited when talking about the Devil (here described as a powerful, knowledgeable scholar). Satan is called *[Trismégiste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Trism%C3%A9giste)* so assimilated to [Hermes Trismegitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes_Trismegistus) (combination of Hermes and Thoth), the God who created all arts and science, including alchemy.

Here is an excerpt from Alexandre Dumas *Un alchimiste au XIXe siècle* (1843) about *chimie* and *alchimie*:

> Mon ami se décida pour la chimie, ou plutôt pour l’alchimie.
>   Il y a un abîme entre ces deux sciences, qui, à la vue, cependant, n’offrent une différence que de deux lettres de plus ou de
>   deux lettres de moins. L’une est une science positive, l’autre est
>   un art conjectural. L’alchimie est le rêve des imaginations puissantes, la chimie est l’étude des esprits graves. Tout chimiste
>   supérieur a commencé par être quelque peu alchimiste.

The Devil as a *chimiste* can also be opposed to God as an *architecte*. The latter is building/creating things while the former is destroying/melting them.

When looking closer to the last verses, Satan is kind of vaporizing gold, i.e. is destroying it. Quite the opposite of what the alchemist were after.

Based on that, I would say ***chimiste*** was used on purpose so the four translations are losing a part of Baudelaire's intent by using the reductive *alchimiste*.

Comment: Speaking to the technical constraints, it's also worth noting that among the English translations Siegel's is the only one without meter, and *chemist* is much less useful for meters with stressed line ends. Moreover, three of the English ones rhyme and woe to the poet who tries to rhyme *chemist*. ("Dentist" perhaps, provided the "t" goes wherever [Lenny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgqtBm_oUpc) left it?) Speaking to the meaning, I think you're on the nose about vaporizing the rare metal. Far from performing alchemy, Satan reverses the process.

Comment: yes, the “vaporizing metals” is really the critical part. It *is* just chemistry because it is *possible* to do by a chemical process. For example, nitric acid or a mixture of nitric acid and hydrochloric acid can dissolve “riche métal” like silver or gold.

Answer (score 4):

Il me semble que présumer qu'un auteur comme Baudelaire aurait dû utiliser un mot (alchimiste) mais ne l'a pas fait pour une seule raison technique (l'alexandrin) est très réducteur.

On peut retrouver ce terme à nouveau dans [cette ébauche d'épilogue](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal_-_%C3%89bauche_d%E2%80%99un_%C3%A9pilogue_pour_la_2e_%C3%A9dition), avec pourtant cette fois une allusion directe à l'alchimie.

*Comme un parfait chimiste et comme une âme sainte.*

*Car j’ai de chaque chose extrait la quintessence,*

*Tu m’as donné ta boue et j’en ai fait de l’or.*

Mais, concernant l'époque de Baudelaire, le dictionnaire Littré de 1873 ("Les fleurs du mal" est paru en 1857) définit l'alchimie par ["chimie du moyen âge..."](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5406710m/f171.item.zoom) et la chimie par ["science dans laquelle..."](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5406710m/f673.item.zoom). Nous ne sommes donc pas à une période de transition entre la chimie et l'alchimie et, probablement, Baudelaire ne pouvait confondre les deux.

Sur un autre plan, dans cette introduction "Au lecteur", Baudelaire décrit une réalité, la sienne, qu'il nous invite à partager ("mon frère"). Il semble qu'au-delà de l'allégorie, il parle donc bien d'une vérité (la chimie) et non pas d'anciennes croyances (l'alchimie).

PS: étant nouveau sur ce site, et considérant cette petite analyse comme une interprétation, une opinion, j'espère ne pas contrevenir à ses règles.

---

Is it legitimate to presume an author such as Baudelaire should have chosen a word (alchemist) but did not only for technical reasons (alexandrine) ?

This word is also present in this [outline of epilogue](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal_-_%C3%89bauche_d%E2%80%99un_%C3%A9pilogue_pour_la_2e_%C3%A9dition), but with, this time, a direct allusion of what we call alchemy.

*Comme un parfait chimiste et comme une âme sainte.*

*Car j’ai de chaque chose extrait la quintessence,*

*Tu m’as donné ta boue et j’en ai fait de l’or.*

But the Littré dictionary of 1873 defines alchemy by ["chemistry of the middle age..."](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5406710m/f171.item.zoom) et chemistry by ["science in which..."](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5406710m/f673.item.zoom). So we are not here in a transition period between alchemy and chemistry, and probably, Baudelaire was aware of that.

On another plan, in this opening poem "to the reader", Baudelaire describes a reality, his own, which he invites us to share ("mon frère"). So it seems that, above the allegory, he's talking about truth (the chemistry) and not about ancient beliefs (alchemy).

Comment: Les règles voudraient que vous répondiez uniquement à la question posée dans votre réponse. Vous faites référence à une autre proposition de réponse. Ce n'est pas nécessaire. Faites le dans une remarque. Mais j'aime la fin de votre réponse ;)

Comment: @jcm69, je suis d'accord avec vous et j'ai réagi car un peu choqué de conclure si vite que le "vrai" mot aurait dû être "alchimiste". Jlliagre a d'ailleurs édité sa réponse pour modérer cet aspect. On aurait pu citer "l'alchimie de la douleur". Le titre n'est pas contraint à l'alexandrin mais aussi "alchimie" peut avoir un sens sensiblement différent d'alchimiste, du moins en français. "il se passe une alchimie" quelque chose qu'on n'explique pas, alors que l'alchimiste est un acteur conscient. Ici le diable n'est clairement pas un acteur qui tatonne... du moins il me semble.

Comment: yes, in a way, the anachronism of “chimiste” in the mythological context has the effect of waking the reader: the threat is real and present now.

Comment: For a fringe interpretation, one could also say Baudelaire hints at *real* chemicals that dissolve our willpower, that is psychoactive drugs. He certainly had some experiences with that. ;-)

Comment: @lemon je me suis permis cette remarque uniquement parce que vous précisiez être nouveau etc. De nombreuses réponses, dont des miennes, ne sont pas très réglementaires... Il n'y a pas mort d'homme ! :)

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats, yes I agree. I've allowed myself to post the question here and in the comments I have the same hypothesis as yours. https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/accuracy-of-a-translation-how-to-forge-an-opinion. I will notify you here if I get some more interesting information.

Comment: @jcm69, il n'y a pas de souci. Merci de cette remarque.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant sentences are the last two

> Et le riche métal de notre volonté
>   Est tout vaporisé par ce savant chimiste.

Baudelaire mentions *"le riche métal"* that clearly references gold. Moreover, alchemists have for centuries tried (in vain) to turn lead into gold. The point is that although Baudelaire wrote "chimiste" for alexandrine requirements, the words express the idea of the alchemists all time dream. Hence the chosen translation.

Sorry for my poor wording, but I am neither native nor a poet.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the translation of "chimiste" is indeed "chemist".

Apparently here the translators chose to use "alchemist" since the rest of the strophe is about alchemical references, and my bet is that they feeled that they had to use [compensation](https://www.nakedtranslations.com/fr/2010/procede-de-traduction-compensation/).

The French text clearly carries alchemical references, and they may have think that their translation would be closer to the original tone if they used "alchemist".

Comment: Ça participerait de la compensation que d'évaluer les connotations ? Le sujet du site n'est pas la langue anglaise, mais justement ne serait-ce pas parce qu'en anglais _alchemist_ est plus symboliste qu'il ne l'est en français qu'on l'aurait choisi ? Merci.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason that very few of the translations use the word *chemist* is that there don't seem to be any perfect rhymes in English for *chemist*. The word *chemist* has stress on the first syllable, and you would need to find a feminine rhyme, which is much harder in English; *menaced* is the closest rhyme I can think of for *chemist* (they rhyme except that /m/ is replaced by the similar consonant /n/).

However, *alchemist* rhymes with both *Trismegist* and *resist*, a fact the translations you quote took advantage of.

Comment: Actually, in a comment to my related answer on the [literature stackexchange,](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/accuracy-of-a-translation-how-to-forge-an-opinion/6229?noredirect=1#comment11699_6229) it was pointed out that *premised* is a perfect rhyme for *chemist*, although it would be hard to work that into a translation of *Au Lecteur*.